# Defining a custom state machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to make it so that people can define arbitrary workflows in classes. The code for this is probably too long for Stack Overflow and so I've got **[a gist](https://gist.github.com/3051916)** for it.

If you run the code, the first couple of tests will work, but when it attempts to transition to the payment state, it checks for the `payment_required?` method on the complete wrong object. I want it to be checking for it on the current `Order` instance, but instead it (seemingly) is looking for that method on the state machine anonymous class.

How do I get it to call the method correctly on the `Order` instance?

Comment: Is that a typo on line 142? Looks like it should be stubbing a predicate method "payment_required?" rather than just "payment_required".

Comment: I really don't understand where this `:payment_required` is defined. You have written `go_to :payment, :if => :order` not `go_to :payment, :if => :payment_required`. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the definition of the anonymous state machine, around line 42:

```
  order.class.transitions.each { |attrs| transition(attrs) }
```

This means the transition guards are evaluated in the anonymous state machine's context rather than in the context of the `Order` class.

One solution would be to translate the transition guards. Replace the above line with this to pass your test suite:

```
  order.class.transitions.each do |attrs| 
    if attrs[:if].is_a? Symbol
      if_method = attrs[:if]
      attrs[:if] = lambda { order.send( if_method ) } 
    end

    transition(attrs)
  end
```

You will need to support all of the types of transition guards for a full solution. Would recommend looking at [`StateMachine::EvalHelpers`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/blob/master/lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb) for the complete set.

**Correction:**

As others have mentioned, you will also need to fix your test suite:

```
go_to :payment, :if => :payment_required? # Line 107

order.stub :payment_required? => true # Line 142
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this up by moving the state machine definition to the `Spree::Order` class. You can see the work in [this pull request](https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/1743).